# On Google app engine web applications, what are the authentication options other than Google identity platforms?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-oauth, openid, google-app-engine-python, google-openid

Can a login/ authentication page for a Google app engine (python)  web application be created, without using the Google identity platform (but possibly a platform common for users having emails on other domains)?
Note: Other email address domains not other social media applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Google Account doesn't require a @gmail.com domain. Other email domains are accepted as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/overview#google_account). When you access to the "Google account signup page", click on "Use my current email address instead" to use it.

You can implement another authentication platform, as Alexander Trakhimenok mentioned, but I don't understand how can this help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried using the 'use my current email address instead'  option though it works you have to go through a long process to register and it is very confusing on first sight for the user as you are logging on to gmail using your yahoo.com domain.

Comment: can a login /authenticate page be created which uses your email address and password of your domain and is not specific to your web app (basically I would prefer not to have the passwords on my database just use authentication by their own specific email domains.) This is possible only for gmail users or is there a way all domain users?

Comment: Users have to authenticate in GAE so they can be identified. If you are trying to use a @yahoo.com account is ok, but you have to save it in the platform (plus password, etc.) to identify the user somehow. Google cannot access Yahoo users/password data.  
Find here an [Authentication overview](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/).

Answer (score 0):

Google AppEngine is a generic platform and you can implement any authentication option that supports web. For example Facebook Connect, Linked In, GitHub, etc.

Refer to a specific authentication platform documentation for implementation details.

Comment: Yes, I have referred to the authentication options in the  google app engine documentation, but there is no mention of authenticating users having other email domain other than gmail.com .

Comment: I am interested in creating a login page in which user can login using his email id and password of any domain like yahoo.com or any custom domain.

Comment: You should either to create your own auth module (login|email/password) or use some 3d party (e.g. Facebook Connect). AppEngine has nothing to do with this and so can't have documentation on this.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend Flask.  It has all the built-in authentication that you seek: login, logout, send email verification, reset password, sessions, CSRF protection, etc.:

http://flask.pocoo.org/